# Exception on trying to change the state in Flex 3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I am trying to change the stage state to different state on click of a button. The problem is `some times` am getting exception as `The supplied DisplayObject must be child of the caller`.
Here is what am trying to do to change the state

```
this.currentState = 'fullScreen';
```

here `this` is a `canvas`.

Here is the MXML for the State `fullscreen`

```
<mx:State name="fullScreen">
            <mx:RemoveChild target="{lstExpert}"/>
            <mx:RemoveChild target="{screenToggle}"/>

            <mx:AddChild  relativeTo="{outContainer}" position="firstChild">
                <mx:HBox id="topHeaderBox" horizontalAlign="left" verticalAlign="middle" width="98.5%" height="60"/>
            </mx:AddChild>

            <mx:AddChild relativeTo="{topHeaderBox}" position="firstChild" >
                <mx:Label id="lblCourseName" width="100%"  text="Name" color="#ffffff" fontFamily="Arial" fontSize="14" fontWeight="bold" height="20" />    
            </mx:AddChild>

            <mx:AddChild target="{screenToggle}" relativeTo="{lblCourseName}" position="after" />



            <mx:AddChild relativeTo="message" position="before">
                <mx:Spacer id="Bar" height="5" width="2" />
            </mx:AddChild>
</state>
```

What would be the mistake here?

Comment: Any other info about the context? For instance the MXML file where the states are defined, or the ActionScript segment where you handle the state change. Because a simple assignment is not enough to get a feel of the problem.

Comment: Edited the question, with the MXML for new state

Answer (score 0):

You might want to bind the `relativeTo` property value of the last `AddChild` object. Meaning, to write it like this:

```
<mx:AddChild relativeTo="{message}" position="before">
```

Assuming you have an element with that id.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks a lot for your response, but that doesnt solves the probelm, one more thing i should mention here that i saw 'firebug/getChild()' in the stack trace, unfortunately i couldnt copy that. Is opening firebug/flashbug would cause this error?

Comment: I could reproduce that.. in the stack trace i found a line as at import::FireBug/onAdded.. please find the screen shot (http://i1155.photobucket.com/albums/p559/veeru-as/Stateexception.png)